# AJAX Request returning No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser

How can I append the stock price and other information returned to the Div?

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function getResults(){
         alert();
         $.get( "http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL", function( data ) {
             document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = data;
             alert( "Load was performed." );
          });
     }

</script>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h2>Click here to start</h2>
    <button type="button" onclick="getResults()">Request Price</button>
    <div id="myDiv">
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's JSONP so you should be able to fetch it cross domain, but it seems jQuery needs to have the dataType set, so doing this should work

```js
function getResults(){
  $.ajax({
    url  : 'http://dev.markitondemand.com/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp',
    data : {symbol : "AAPL"},
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'jsonp'
  }).done(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Click here to start</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="getResults()">Request Price</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kfhtL3kx/)